# Retrieving timestamp data from Django models

Tags: python, html, django

New to Django and am having some issues trying to display the timestamps from my models in my code.
I have two Django classes representing two different lists:

```
models.py


class Playinglist(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    game_id = models.IntegerField()
    started_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Playedlist(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    game_id = models.IntegerField()
    finished_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

When I create a new model I understand that `models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)` should create a timestamp in the model for when that model was last saved.

The functions I am using to add data to these models look like this:

```
views.py


def add_to_playinglist(request, game_id):
    obj = Playinglist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)

    if obj:
        obj.delete()
        game = Game.objects.get(id=game_id)
        playing_game = Playinglist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)
        return redirect("profile")
    else:
        obj = Playinglist()
        obj.user = request.user.username
        obj.game_id = game_id
        obj.save()
        game = Game.objects.get(id=game_id)
        playing_game = Playinglist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)
        return redirect("profile")
    

@login_required(login_url='/login')
def add_to_playedlist(request, game_id):
    obj = Playedlist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)

    if obj:
        obj.delete()
        game = Playinglist.objects.get(game_id=game_id)
        played_game = Playedlist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)
        return redirect("profile")
    else:
        obj = Playedlist()
        obj.user = request.user.username
        obj.game_id = game_id
        obj.save()
        
        game = Playinglist.objects.get(game_id=game_id)
        game.delete()

        played_game = Playedlist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)
        return redirect("profile")
```

And when I try displaying the data I use these functions:

```
views.py


playinglist = Playinglist.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)
    playinglist_items = []
    playing = playinglist.count()
    present_in_playinglist = False
    if playinglist:
        for item in playinglist:
            try:
                game = Game.objects.get(id=item.game_id)
                playinglist_items.append(game)
                present_in_playinglist = True
                
            except:
                present_in_playinglist = False

    playedlist = Playedlist.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)
    playedlist_items = []
    finished = playedlist.count()
    present_in_playedlist = False
    if playedlist:
        for item in playedlist:
            try:
                game = Game.objects.get(id=item.game_id)
                playedlist_items.append(game)
                present_in_playedlist = True

            except:
                present_in_playedlist = False
```

I am having trouble identifying how and where to add code to display these timestamps. For my `playinglist` codeblock, I have tried:

```
playinglist = Playinglist.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)
    playinglist_items = []
    playing = playinglist.count()
    present_in_playinglist = False
    if playinglist:
        for item in playinglist:
            try:
                game = Game.objects.get(id=item.game_id)
                playinglist_items.append(game)
                present_in_playinglist = True
                started_on = Playinglist.objects.get(started_on)
            except:
                present_in_playinglist = False
```

And to display this I am using and html page to render it:

```
profile.html

{% if present_in_playinglist %}
   {% for game in playinglist_items %}
      <p>Started on: {{ started_on }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
{% else %}
   <h6>No games currently playing.</h6>
{% endif %}
```

However when I do this it seems to override my `playinglist` and not return anything. Am I writing this incorrectly, or am I putting this line in the wrong place?

**EDIT**

I tried something else and this seems to get the timestamps:

```
playinglist = Playinglist.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)
    playinglist_items = []
    playing = 0
    present_in_playinglist = False
    if playinglist:
        for item in playinglist:
            try:
                game = Game.objects.get(id=item.game_id)
                playinglist_items.append(game)
                present_in_playinglist = True
                playing += 1
                playinglist = Playinglist.objects.get(id=item.game_id)
                
            except:
                present_in_playinglist = False

    playedlist = Playedlist.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)
    playedlist_items = []
    finished = 0
    present_in_playedlist = False
    if playedlist:
        for item in playedlist:
            try:
                game = Game.objects.get(id=item.game_id)
                playedlist_items.append(game)
                present_in_playedlist = True
                finished += 1
                playedlist = Playedlist.objects.get(game_id=item.game_id)

            except:
                present_in_playedlist = False

    context = {
        "playinglist": playinglist,
        "playedlist": playedlist,
        "present_in_playlist": present_in_playlist,
        "playlist_items": playlist_items,
        "saved": saved,
        "present_in_playinglist": present_in_playinglist,
        "playinglist_items": playinglist_items,
        "playing": playing,
        "present_in_playedlist": present_in_playedlist,
        "playedlist_items": playedlist_items,
        "finished": finished
    }

    return render(request, "capstone/profile.html", context)
```

And my html render looks like this now:
`<p>Started on: {{ playinglist.started_on }}</p>`

However in this solution, whenever I move an item from one model to the next it will update the timestamps for every item in that list. I seem to be stuck in a loop somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the `started_on` value properly in the loop and also it's important to pass the variable to the context so that it can be used in your template.

Do these->

Update your `views.py` file with this code below:

```
if playinglist:
    for item in playinglist:
        try:
            game = Game.objects.get(id=item.game_id)
            playinglist_items.append({'game': game, 'started_on': item.started_on})
            present_in_playinglist = True
        except:
            present_in_playinglist = False
```

Then update your template `profile.html` with this:

```
{% if present_in_playinglist %}
    {% for game in playinglist_items %}
        <p>Started on: {{ game.started_on }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <h6>No games currently playing.</h6>
{% endif %}
```

This should fix the issue you are having. If any questions feel free to ask in the comment section.

Comment: I made an edit to the post. I tried your solution and was getting several errors. The one I posted in the edit seems to get the timestamps but will add that timestamp to every item in the list rather than a single item.